# Linux Kernel SKB with empty ARP bytes set to zero

Tags: linux-kernel, network-interface, kernel-modules, arp

I am registering a netdevice notifier in kernel using:

`netdev_rx_handler_register(dev, my_handler, data)`

Upon receiving network SKBs I check them, and if ethertype is set to `ETH_P_ARP` I print `skb->data` which should contain ARP information, however all bytes are set to 0, even though `skb->len` corresponds to ARP request length.

It works on my regular PC, and prints ARP fields properly, but fails on remote enterprise level server.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with 5.15.0-87-generic on both environments.

Could this be related to netdevice or this is a system level issue?